# How can I reliably reset the Woocommerce user selected shipping method in the cart during testing?

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, testing, woocommerce

According to a conversation with a Woocommerce developer on Github recently.

> once you've calculated shipping, or chosen a method, or gone to cart/checkout, the selected method will stick and override your default.

Is there a simple way during testing to guarantee that the user selected shipping method has been reset. I have tried various combinations of hard refresh/incognito mode/re opening the browser/clearing cookies/transients etc but I can't be sure of a simple reliable way to reset it so I can test properly.

I can guess that if I was to do all the above there's a likelihood that it would have been reset but for testing I want to a) know for certain and b) reset the user input with the least amount of work as it may be repeated multiple times.

**Edit:** I have discovered that clicking **clear sessions** in the woocommerce status>tools section does seem to do this, but again I'm looking for an authoritative answer

**Edit 2:** I'm looking for an operational way to do this, not a programmatic one.

Comment: Please be a service to the community and properly explain downvotes. The question follows the guidelines in "What topics can I ask about here?" is properly formatted, has good grammar and is not subjective.

Comment: `Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming` But woocommerce is a programming tool, or at least I build it to use sites anyway.

Comment: "I'm looking for an operational way to do this, not a programmatic one."

Comment: `involve tools used primarily for programming`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [WooCommerce Shipping Class](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-shipping.php). Specifically, the [reset_shipping()](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-shipping.php#L395) method.

You can reset the chosen shipping method that has been stored to the session via:

```
<?php unset( WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods ); ?>
```

**EDIT:** A non-programmatic way to do this is to head to the WP Admin Dashboard and navigate to: `WooCommerce --> System Status --> Tools` and click "Clear all sessions" under the "Customer Sessions" section.

As the message states, this will **delete all session data from the database** for all customers. This includes live carts and chosen shipping methods (which, as you can see from my programmatic answer above, are included in the WooCommerce session).

Comment: That's not really the question I'm asking but thanks ... I am looking for a way to reset it as an administrator, not programmaticaly like you've shown ... or do you mean just run this once and then comment it out or something?

Comment: I'm not sure why I was down voted. This site is *for* programming. Of course I'm going to give a programmatic answer.

Comment: @byronyasgur I have edited my answer to include a way to do this without programming

Comment: Thanks for that; but Stack Overflow is not completely _limited_ to specific programming questions ... see [what topics are covered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I don't think the question actually deserve a downvote either, but looks like I got one for some reason ... there's a lot of weird bitchiness here lately IMO

Comment: @rnevius answer is the best answer even if it is not the answer you wanted to hear.  Either you do it with a snippet of code as suggested or you can use the admin dashboard and do a broad 'clear all sessions'.  Clearing the sessions is probably a bad plan unless you are in a testing enviroment as it will affect all live carts, not just the one you are wanting to clear.

Comment: @greg_diesel  But why would you think I wouldn't want to hear it? I have just now accepted it as the answer and awarded the bounty. The only reason I didn't do it earlier was because I was ideally looking for an authoritative answer, but I'm fairly sure this one covers it. Your premise sounds dubious ... are you one of the people doing the mysterious downvotes by any chance?  Please see my note above if you are; if not apologies .... BTW I should have added in my question that I'm in a testing environment. I wrongly presumed that was obvious.

Comment: My answer is authoritative...Again [the source for clicking that button](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/40c86a9e4afee1d5150a5e38138cdc6fb8b6da5f/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-status.php#L113) will prove that. It deletes all session data from the database, which includes the shipping class.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know you meant that ... it's not apparent from the answer that's it's not just your best guess. The source only tells me that it clears the sessions ( as does the text on the button ) ... it does not tell me that it is guaranteed to reset the shipping method as I don't know the shipping method is stored in a session for certain.